# How do I hide the border in a RadControls for Winforms RadScrollablePanel

Tags: winforms, telerik, border, rad-controls

I have a RadScrollablePanel that I want to hide the border. You'd think that:

RadScrollablePanel1.PanelContainer.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

would work, but it doesnt. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do this:

```
radScrollablePanel1.PanelElement.Border.Visibility =
        Telerik.WinControls.ElementVisibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just by setting `ElementVisibility.Collapsed` border still remained:

```
cpnlLessUsedFields.ControlsContainer.PanelElement.Border.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Collapsed;
```

I had to do this, to get it to not show the border:

```
cpnlLessUsedFields.ControlsContainer.PanelContainer.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
cpnlLessUsedFields.ControlsContainer.PanelElement.Border.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Collapsed;`
```